# iOS 7 Address book not sorted

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, addressbook

I am making a contacts app and was testing it in iOS 7 simulator using XCode 5. I noticed that if I launch Apple's contacts app within the simulator and create a bunch of new contacts, the ones that come pre-built with XCode are not getting sorted. Notice John Appleseeds is listed under "#" while he should be under "A". Can I fix this? Its annoying the #@!$ out of me while I try to implement custom sort in my own app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe just delete the contacts?

Comment: I would like to fix them if possible

Comment: It is an annoying bug in the iOS Simulator. Basically, just go into each of the contact, press edit, then press done. When you go back it is no longer in the # section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested in future this is how I fixed it.

- Launch Simulator on its own
- Touch each and every contact and change their first name Like David to Dave
- Click on your Simulator home button to exit out of contacts app then shutdown simulator
- Launch it again and go to contacts app. Everything will be sorted and no one will be under #
  section.

What fun .... In another life I will be a baker.